# Equation of tangent to a circle

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Find an equation of the tangent to the circle with equation $x^2+y^2-10x+4y+4=0$ at the point $(2,2)$

I have solved up to $4y - 8 = 3x - 6$, but I am not sure whether the final answer should be $3x-4y+2=0$ OR whether it should be $y=\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{1}{2}$.

The solutions say $3x-4y+2=0$ should be the answer; however, it doesn't ask for a specific form of the equation.  Could it be both?

Comment: I have solved the equation I am asking if the final form of the equation is correct ?

Comment: it should be +1/2.

Comment: Both are equivalent, and one is just the other with one of the variables isolated. Unless there are other instructions that you did not mention, both are admissible answers (after correcting the sign in the constant term).

Comment: Thank you I understand and yes I've corrected that now.

Comment: The problem says "find **an** equation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I'd use neither!

The important parts here are that it *passes through a particular point* and *goes in a particular direction*, which means that point-slope form is best:

$$y-2 = \frac{3}{4}(x-2)$$

Comment: well, yes, the form  you suggest has also the advantage to be easily checkable